# Most elegant way to prove a prime is a prime?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, prime-numbers, alternative-proof

Taking say 103, the best way I can think of is to square root it (giving 10.14889), then say that all factors must be below that root, then show that 103 is not divisible by 2,3,5,7 (prime factors below the square root), and is therefore prime?

Is there a better way to prove it is a prime, or is this the best way?

Comment: What is your criterion for "best"?

Comment: Calculating 5 decimal places of the square root is certainly not elegant. All you need is the integer part of the square root.

Comment: @RobertIsrael as stated in title "elegant", basically the shortest amount of lines whilst retaining easy understanding and readability

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know my method is clunky, thats why i'm asking this question

Comment: Then there is an easy answer. There a lots of better algorithms, and you should google "primality tests". For $103$ however, I find your method quite good. Only, the square root estimate is nonsense, because divisors are integers. So you could have said, test small prime divisors up to $11$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: minor quibble: you don't have to test $11$.

Comment: @RobArthan There is no *mathematical* reason to test 11, but let's not discount the possible psychological reasons. Of course, from the computer's perspective, the optimization of ignoring the prime immediately above $\sqrt n$ is negligible, though it would of course be good form on the part of the programmer.

Comment: @RobertSoupe: I agree that the cost of one more division is asymptotically negligible. All the ways I can think of for calculating the integer square will tell you if the number is a perfect square for free: so if you are only interested in primality testing (rather than finding factors), you won't have to do any trial divisions for perfect squares.

Comment: @RobArthan: Like I said, there's no mathematical reason to do that one more division. But some people suffer minor psychological afflictions. They know well enough not to test every prime below $n$. and understand why they don't need to go beyond $\sqrt n$, but they have a psychological compulsion to test that one prime just above the threshold.

Comment: @RobertSoupe:please reread my last comment:  someone doing the necessary computations will detect perfect squares before they embark on trial divisions. I find your remarks about psychological afflictions and compulsions bizarre and unconvincing - where are you getting this psychological evidence from?

Comment: @RobArthan From trying to tutor two of my young nephews. One of them was later diagnosed with something like Asperger's, I don't remember exactly, but I do know he understood when he was doing something that is not necessary. The other one is as dumb as a bag of rocks, he'll test up to $n$ itself.

Comment: @RobertSoupe: intersting. Thanks for the anecdotal evidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For small odd numbers, say below $10^6$, there is just no better way than trial division: try dividing $n$ by each prime less than $\sqrt n$ and see what happens. Heck, you can even try dividing by all odd numbers, including composite numbers like $9$ and $15$, with hardly any performance penalty (assuming you're using a computer).

When you go above $10^{10}$ (these are not hard limits, more like fuzzy gray lines) things start getting hairy and you need something more elegant in order to get results in your lifetime.

For example, is $2^{44501} - 1$ prime? This is a number with more than ten thousand digits in base $10$, and $44500$ bits in binary. Trial division just won't cut it.

Mathematicians have developed all kinds of tests for primes of special forms. I could be wrong, but $103$ doesn't seem all that special. Now consider a number like $127$. It's special because it's $2^7 - 1$. Because $11 < \sqrt{127}$, it's enough to test the primes $3, 5, 7, 11$.

The Lucas-Lehmer test applied to $127$ seems kind of overkill, except for pedagogic purposes. Set $LL_0 = 4$, and then $LL_n = (LL_{n - 1})^2 - 2$. If $2^p - 1$ is prime, then $LL_{p - 2} \equiv 0 \pmod{2^p - 1}$. The proof is too long to repeat here but can be found on the Web easily enough. So modulo $127$, we have: $4, 14, 194, 42,  111, 0$, bingo!

When you start to look at numbers like $2^{31} - 1$, then you can really appreciate things like the Lucas-Lehmer test. But to deal with large odd numbers that don't seem to be of any special form, there are algorithms like Pollard $p - 1$ and Pollard $\rho$, which have their best case and worst case scenarios (e.g., hardly any better than trial division).